# Excel, copying cell between sheets based on criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, copy

I need to copy cells from one sheet to the other based on another cell.

If cell.columnA from sheet1 contains the text from cell.columnA from sheet2, copy cell.columnB, cell.columnC, cell.columnD from sheet1 to sheet2.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: This is possible, both via macros ("on demand") and formulas ("immediately"). If you go with formulas, a simple IF-formula will do, just read into that and come back if anything is unclear. For macros it will be a bit more complex (though not too difficult for a beginner). First you need to decide what you want, then come back to ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely possible.  I would use the `if` and `vlookup` functions.  Something like this:

```
=IF($A1=Sheet1!$A1, VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A1, Sheet1!$A1:$D1, 2),"")
```

The dollar signs lock the columns so you can paste over many rows, the if checks for equality of column a values, Sheet1!$A1:$D1 is the range you specified between columns a through d, and the 2 represents the second column in that range.  This example was for column b in row 1 on sheet 2.

Comment: vlookup is not even neccessary.

Comment: I would prefer to change which column in a range I'm in.  There are other ways it can be calculated.  This one feels cleaner to me.

Comment: Sorry, I am very basic with this, please be patient. How does it know to compare to the different sheets with that if statement?

Comment: Because the formula is in sheet 2, it defaults to sheet 2 if you don't say otherwise.  So the first part of the if is the condition.  `$A1=Sheet1!$A1` is saying A1 from Sheet2 is equal to A1 from Sheet1?  If it it true, then it calculates the second part.

Comment: The second part of the if only calculates if the first part is true.  `vlookup' may not be the simplest way, but it looks for a value `Sheet1!$A1` in a range `Sheet1!$A1:$D1` and when it finds a match, will go to whichever column you specify to pull the value.  In this example, colB=2, colC=3, colD=4.

Comment: Ok, so in my actual application. I need to compare sheet2.ColD to sheet1.ColA. how do I copy cells Sheet1.colB;Sheet1.colC;Sheet1.colD; to sheet2.ColF;sheet2.ColG;sheet2.ColH?

Comment: You'd either have to change the range (wider, taller) to surround all your data, or you can replace the `vlookup` with `Sheet1!B1` where b1 is whichever cell you're trying to copy.

Comment: Sorry, I have been asking the wrong question. I was thinking that it was cell per cell. This isn't the case. There is a small list in sheet1. Is there a way to compare Sheet2.ColD to all of Sheet1.ColA, not a specific cell, but all of Column A. If so copy Sheet1.ColB:D of that row to Sheet2.ColF:H ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Is the list a drop down in a single cell?  Or is it values listed vertically from row 1 downward?  If you are looking for a match in a list that you don't know which row your information will be on, you have to use `vlookup`.  Just make sure your range is appropriate and you are referencing the proper columns.